# Find entries from related section after certain date

Tags: entries, relations, craft3

Does anyone know how to achieve the following in Twig with Craft 3:

My sections
**locations** and **trainings**.

I want to find all the entries from **locations** which has a relation to **trainings** and a datetime field value from **trainings** has to be after now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’d first get all the relevant entries of your “trainings” section, or better get just their IDs as that’s way better on performance.
Then on another element query you set the `relatedTo` parameter to only get entries related to these entry IDs.

```
{% set trainingsEntriesIds = craft.entries({
    section: 'trainings',
    postDate: '>= ' ~ 'now'|date('c'),
}).ids() %}

{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'locations',
    relatedTo: {
        targetElement: trainingsEntriesIds,
        field: 'entriesFieldHandle'
    },
}).all() %}
```